How to implement first run preferences using Preferences Datastore in Java?
I'm currently working on an Android application using Java and following the MVVM architecture pattern. In my application, I need to save a boolean value to determine if the app has been opened for the first time and navigate to a specific fragment. I'm attempting to accomplish this using Preferences DataStore along with RxJava.
Being new to Preference DataStore and RxJava, I followed the Android developer documentation and ended up with the following code.
Here's the repository code:
public class PreferencesRepository {

    private final RxDataStore<Preferences> preferencesDataStore;
    private static final Preferences.Key<Boolean> FIRST_RUN_KEY = PreferencesKeys.booleanKey("first_run");

    public PreferencesRepository(RxDataStore<Preferences> preferencesDataStore) {
        this.preferencesDataStore = preferencesDataStore;
    }

    public Flowable<Boolean> getFirstRunPref() {
        return preferencesDataStore.data()
                .map(prefs -> prefs.get(FIRST_RUN_PREF) != null ? prefs.get(FIRST_RUN_PREF) : true);
    }

    public void setFirstRunPref(boolean value) {
        Single<Preferences> updateResult = preferencesDataStore.updateDataAsync(prefsIn -> {
            MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = prefsIn.toMutablePreferences();
            Boolean currentKey = prefsIn.get(FIRST_RUN_KEY);
            mutablePreferences.set(FIRST_RUN_KEY, currentKey == null || value);
            return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
        });
    }
}

This is the View Model code:
public final class SampleViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final PreferencesRepository repository;

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> firstRunPref;

    public SampleViewModel(PreferencesRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getFirstRunPrefValue() {
        if (firstRunPref == null) {
            firstRunPref = new MutableLiveData<>();
            firstRunPref.postValue(repository.getFirstRunPref().blockingFirst());
        }
        return firstRunPref;
    }
}

The Activity code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore;

    private SampleViewModel sampleViewModel;

    private PreferencesRepository repository;

    private boolean isFirstRun;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        dataStore = new RxPreferencesDataStoreBuilder(this, "preferences").build();

        repository = new PreferencesRepository(dataStore);

        sampleViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new SampleViewModelFactory(repository)).get(SampleViewModel.class);

        final Observer<Boolean> firstRunObserver = aBoolean -> {
            isFirstRun = aBoolean;
        };

        sampleViewModel.getFirstRunPrefValue().observe(this, firstRunObserver);

        if (isFirstRun) {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2);
        }
    }
}

The main problem arises in the MainActivity where isFirstRun is never initialized in time for the navigation logic, always resulting in false. I've attempted to move the navigation logic inside the observer, but encountered crashes when configuration changes occur.
I've looked for examples online, but most of them are in Kotlin, and the available Java samples are quite basic. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
